# Openlayers 3.5 feature disappear

Tags: openlayers-3

so I updated my openlayers version from v3.0 to v3.5. I created a feature overlay to be added to my map as a bounding box, for my search extense functionality.  I noticed that my feature overlay would disappear from my map whenever my cursor is not directly over my map and reappear when my cursor gets back on my map.  This was not the case on the old version of openlayers, v3.0. Anyone knows of the changes that may have caused this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, something related to `map.on('pointermove', callback)`

Comment: I saw something about that on the openlayers update documentation. I just don't see how it would affect my code since I don't use mousemove or pointermove in my code.  Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: How about an online demo?